# How i can add like on product page

Tags: python, django

I can like my products from admin panel,and i want to add posibility to like them by url **products/item/like**,i have view of like but i dont know what i should add to there.This is my **views.py**

```
class LikeToggleView(AjaxResponseMixin, JSONResponseMixin, FormView):
    http_method_names = ('post',)
    form_class = LikeForm
    product = None

    @csrf_exempt
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        product_id = kwargs['product_pk']
        try:
            self.product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
        except Product.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404()
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

this is **forms.py**

```
class LikeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    user = forms.ModelChoiceField(User.objects.all(), required=False)
    product = forms.ModelChoiceField(Product.objects.all())
    ip = forms.GenericIPAddressField(required=True)
```

this is **models.py**

```
class Like(TimeStampedModel):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='likes')
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='likes')
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('product', 'user'), ('product', 'ip'))

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} from {}'.format(self.product, self.user or self.ip)
```

Comment: First of all you should add a desired boolean field to your `Like` model like for example `is_liked` which values to True once someone liked the Product. Otherwise you would have to remove/add entries on Like toggling. Then in your view you just change the boolean once toggled..